# Bootstrap form input edges wont change from rounded to square

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the corners for my form input square instead of rounded in bootstrap but am having no luck. The CSS worked for the button, but the input form is still rounded. What am I doing wrong here?

```
  <form class="navbar-form pull-right">

                    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">

                    <input type="email" class="form-control input" id="email" name="email" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

css

```
 .form-control {
border-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your CSS rule isn't specific enough to override the Bootstrap CSS. Instead, just use :

```
#email {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/UHAbBAMZVW)**

To learn more about CSS specificity, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: You can override it using !important as well

Comment: That might not be the best way to solve it, however targeting an id when you want to target multiple inputs isn't effiicient.

Comment: @DubstepZedd `!important` should be avoided at all costs and in this question there's a single input to be styled, not multiple, otherwise obviously, and ID wouldn't be the optimal solution

Comment: Right, didn't think of that he only needed to affect 1 input. I managed to do it without "!important" anyway which was nice

Answer (score 3):

The simpliest way is to use Bootstrap  border utilities  `rounded-0`

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/borders/

`<input type="email" class="form-control input rounded-0" id="email" name="email" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing .form-control properties

```
.form-control{
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0;
          border-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to make them square,

```
<input type="email" style="border-radius: 0 !important" class="form-control input" id="email" name="email" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
```

Comment: You should avoid using both inline styling and `!important` whenever possible

Answer (score 0):

```
.form-group-sm .form-control {
      border-radius: 0;
}
```

It seems like a specificity issue, modifying `.form-group-sm .form-control { }` removes the border radius.